# svg not displayed in local

Tags: html, svg

I am currently using an svg on an html page which is running on my local machine, and not on a server. The image not display :

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-lead slds-icon--small">
        <use xlink:href="SLDS202/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#lead"></use>
</svg>
```

The path are right. On local machine i have the impression that we can't run the use part. Is that right? I didn't see any limitations by being on a server and been on a local machine.

This code run well on local :

```
 <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
     <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
     <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
  </svg>
```

When inspecting the console, i am getting this error :

```
  Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/work/References/SLDS/SLDS202/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#filterList from frame with URL file:///C:/work/References/SLDS/axa-hk-gi-demo.html.
 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.
```

Comment: If you're using Chrome it's security model prevents local files referring to other files in different directories. Firefox's security model allows local files to refer to other local files provided that the referenced file is in the same directory or a subdirectory of the referrer.

Comment: The SLDS202 folder is a subfolder of where my html page is. The path is right. I think that in local html cannot evaluate that part : symbols.svg#lead. Am i wrong?

Comment: Good question. Its now that I notice that in mozilla it renders well, but not on chrome, and I use chrome by default. But its only blocked on local, when assessing my page on a server it displays.

Comment: Did you read the first sentence in my first comment? Given your reply that seems to be your issue no?

Comment: Yes you are right. This is the isssue :)

Comment: @RobertLongson This should be an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting @RobertLongson's comment which should be an answer:

> If you're using Chrome it's security model prevents local files
>   referring to other files in different directories. Firefox's security
>   model allows local files to refer to other local files provided that
>   the referenced file is in the same directory or a subdirectory of the
>   referrer.